# IdentityServer4 Correlation Failed Error with External Provider

Tags: identityserver4, pingfederate, openid-connect

I am attempting to integrate Ping Federate as an external OIDC provider for my IdentityServer4 instance. When I initiate the external login flow I am getting the following error:

```
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.<HandleRequestAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Hosting\FederatedSignOut\AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.cs:line 38
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Hosting\BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 43
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I'm kind of stumped on why `FederatedSignOut` is even being called. Any ideas on what I may be missing here?

Here is the `AddAuthentication` configuration:

```
services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();

services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("ping", "Ping Federate", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                options.Authority = "https://ping.domain.com/";
                options.ClientId = "IdentityServer4";
                options.ClientSecret = "IdentityServer4";

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I seem to be having exactly the same problem. I can not reproduce it in development environment for there it simply works fine. This only happens when in production.

Comment: I ended up changing `services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();` to `services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache("ping");` and it began working.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in the configuration in startup.cs.   Its an issue with going from http to https.

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
```